# Selenium's finding methods by class and tag show no elements present

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, selenium

I'm trying to extrapolate the preferences from my Netflix account with Selenium. Using the find_elements_by_class_name I managed to login, choose profile, open the account page and change the list from views to ratings, but I can't figure out how to select the movies from the table, since the aforementioned function doesn't show any result when used on their class or tag names.

This is the code I've written so far, and I've only got problems with the last line:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium import webdriver


ch = Options()

ch.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
ch.add_argument("--disable-gpu")
ch.add_argument("--incognito")

browser = webdriver.Chrome(options = ch)
browser.get("https://www.netflix.com/login")

username = browser.find_element_by_id("id_userLoginId")
password = browser.find_element_by_id("id_password")

username.send_keys(input('Insert e-mail: '))
password.send_keys(getpass(prompt = "Insert password: "))
password.send_keys(Keys.ENTER)

profiles = browser.find_elements_by_class_name("profile-name")
print(profiles)

profiles[0].click()
browser.get("https://www.netflix.com/viewingactivity")
browser.find_element_by_class_name("choice.icon.rating").click()

print(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("retableRow"))
```

The Hmtl code I'm referring to is (sorry for the awful formatting):

```html
<ul class="structural retable stdHeight">
<li class="retableRow">
<div class="col date nowrap">05/09/19
</div>
<div class="col title">
<a href="/title/70099111">Watchmen</a></div><div class="col rating nowrap"><div class="thumbs-component thumbs thumbs-horizontal rated rated-up" data-uia="thumbs-container">
<div class="nf-svg-button-wrapper thumb-container thumb-up-container " data-uia="">
<a role="link" data-rating="0" tabindex="0" class="nf-svg-button simpleround" aria-label="Già valutato: pollice alzato (fai clic per rimuovere la valutazione)">
<svg data-rating="0" class="svg-icon svg-icon-thumb-up-filled" focusable="true">
<use filter="" xlink:href="#thumb-up-filled"></use></svg></a></div><div class="nf-svg-button-wrapper thumb-container thumb-down-container " data-uia="">
<a role="link" data-rating="1" tabindex="0" class="nf-svg-button simpleround" aria-label="Valutazione pollice verso">
<svg data-rating="1" class="svg-icon svg-icon-thumb-down" focusable="true"><use filter="" xlink:href="#thumb-down">
</use>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
<div class="nf-svg-button-wrapper clear-rating" data-uia="">
<a role="link" data-rating="0" data-clear-thumbs="true" tabindex="0" class="nf-svg-button simpleround" aria-label="Rimuovi la valutazione">
<svg data-rating="0" data-clear-thumbs="true" class="svg-icon svg-icon-close" focusable="true">
<use filter="" xlink:href="#close">
</use>
</svg>
</a>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</li>
```

It should print a list of all the elements of the class "retableRow", but iit prints an empty list instead. I've tried with the class "col.title" with similar results, and with the tag "li" that gave me totally different elements I'm not interested in. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is only a portion of the full HTML. Is there a chance that this HTML is part of an iframe?

Comment: I couldn't post the whole thing because it was massive, but the xpath for these elements is of the form  "/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div[2]/div/div/ul/li[1]/div[2]", so there is no iframe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to find elements which are not there yet. Probably the page is updated via ajax calls or something.

```py
browser.find_element_by_class_name("choice.icon.rating").click()
time.sleep(1)
print(browser.find_elements_by_class_name("retableRow"))
```

Ta-daam. Wait for it.

A bit more elegant approach would be to wait for element presence and then start parsing.
Example:

```py
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By

def wait_for_elem_by_xpath(xp):
    elem = WebDriverWait(browser, 20).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.XPATH, xp)))
    return elem
```

With this, replace your last line in your sample code to:

```py
your_list = wait_for_elem_by_xpath('//*[@class="retableRow"]')
print(your_list)
```

And it will work.

Comment: Oh my gosh! It was so simple yet I spent so many hours on this... I'm such a noob!
Thank you very much, your kindness has been really appreciated!